# Google sign in button and accessibility

Tags: html, accessibility, google-signin

Any ideas how to make the blue Google sign in button to be focused on the page with using Tab button only, to set focus on it?  (tabindex = 0)

As example, on the page 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button
I'm unable to set a focus for this button with the Tab key.

Any suggestions how to implement it on my website so it may be clicked with the keyboard (Tab, Enter buttons only), but with no mouse?

Thank you.

Comment: Weird that isn't built-in, a simple `tabindex` inside the iframe would do the trick... Best method would probably just follow the guide on [building a completely custom button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button#building_a_button_with_a_custom_graphic).

Comment: While adding a `tabindex` inside the iframe would allow the keyboard focus to move to the "sign in" button, it would **not** allow the button to be activated when pressing space or enter.  The nested iframe is only listening for mouse click events and not keyboard events.

Comment: Note that the iframe on that demo page is for demo purposes.  When you add the signin button to your actual page, you don't get an iframe. It's just a nested `<div>`.  After the signin button is added, you could hack around it by adding a `tabindex` on the `<div class="abcRioButton">` and add an event handler for keyboard presses and force the click() handler to run when you see a space or enter key.  However, your first step should be to send feedback to google to have them make the signin button accessible.

Comment: @slugolicious Don't they allow putting a `button` instead of a `div`? And if no, wouldn't it be enough to add the `button` role and `tabindex`? I know it would be enough for a screen reader user, but don't know if that works without a screen reader *and* with no mouse.

Comment: @andre, I'm not sure how the google signin button actually works but it appears you give it a container that the google api fills with its signin stuff.  Even if the container were a real `<button>`, it would not make the contents of the button a keyboard selectable thing because they only have a click event handler.